# JavaScript, append HTML and reference IDs in function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function

I have a form that shows a drop-down menu and a text field next to it:

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
  <tbody class="project_wrapper">
    <tr>
      <td scope="row">
      <select id="test_project" name="test_project[]">
        <option selected>Select</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>20</option>
      </select>
      </td>
      <td><input id="test_value" name="test_value[]" type="text" placeholder="Enter value"></td>
      <td><div id="test_calc"></div></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_project" title="Add project">Add another project</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

You can select one of the values in the drop-down, and when you enter a numeric value into the text field, on each keyup, it'll display the value multiplied by the selected value. You can also click the "Add another project" link and it'll append/create another drop-down and text field. This already works, and is done with the following Jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  var addProject = $('.add_project');
  var wrapper = $('.project_wrapper');
  var projectHTML = `<tr>
                       <td scope="row">
                       <select id="test_project2" name="test_project[]" class="custom-select">
                         <option selected>Select</option>
                         <option>10</option>
                         <option>20</option>
                       </select>
                       </td>
                       <td><input id="test_value2" name="test_value[]" type="text" placeholder="Enter value"></td>
                    <td><div id="test_calc2"></div></td>
                  </tr>`;

  $(addProject).click(function(){
    $(wrapper).append(projectHTML);
  });
});

$('#test_value').keyup(function(){
  $('#test_calc').text(Math.round($(this).val() * $("#test_project option:selected").val()));
});
```

The problem is I can't get the multiplication function to work/display the result for any newly appended lines. Above you can see I tried hardcoding the values of `test_value2` and `test_calc2` and then added this below:

```
$('#test_value2').keyup(function(){
  $('#test_calc2').text(Math.round($(this).val() * $("#test_project2 option:selected").val()));
});
```

I would expect the result (at least for one new appended line) to appear in the same way as for the first line, but nothing seems to happen. My goal is to get the results to appear for the appended line, and then also find a way to have that keyup calculation function work for any number of appended lines (rather than hardcode 2, 3, 4, etc. values).

The `ids`, I think, will need to be dynamically assigned as the lines are appended, and then the `name` will stay the same to hold the arrays for `test_array` and `test_value` which I'm going to receive and process via PHP.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of input is `type="type"`? You mean `type="number"`?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan whoops, thanks, I was typing this too fast and meant "text", but just double-typed "type". This could definitely be "number" as well since I'm expecting numbers, but I don't want to show the arrows that appear in the text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Remove all your IDs from the template rows, use classes or `name=""` instead as your selectors
- Assign an ID to your TBODY, we'll use it as the [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) event [delegator](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)
- Use the [`"input"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) event, not the `"keydown"` event. You can also copy/paste values, remember?
- on `"input"` - refer to the parent TR using [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) before descending back (using [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)) to find the elements specific for that row
- Use [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) to handle input strings. Also remember to always fallback to a number i.e: `0` to prevent `NaN` results

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  const projectHTML = `<tr>
     <td>
       <select name="test_project[]" class="custom-select">
         <option value="" selected>Select</option>
         <option value="10">10</option>
         <option value="20">20</option>
       </select>
     </td>
     <td><input name="test_value[]" type="type" placeholder="Enter value"></td>
     <td><div class="result"></div></td>
  </tr>`;

  const $projects = $("#projects"); // assign an ID to your tbody
  const $addProject = $('.add_project');
  const arrRow = () => $projects.append(projectHTML);

  // Create new row on click
  $addProject.on("click", arrRow);
  
  // Add the first row
  arrRow(); 

  // use a delegator which is not dymanic (the TBODY in this case),  
  // and use delegated events to any ":input" element:
  
  $projects.on("input", ":input", function(ev) {
    const $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
    
    const $project = $tr.find('[name="test_project[]"]');
    const $value = $tr.find('[name="test_value[]"]');
    const $result = $tr.find(".result");
        
    const project = parseInt($project.val(), 10) || 0;
    const value = parseFloat($value.val()) || 0;
    const result = project * value;
    
    $result.text(result);
  });

});
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="projects"></tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_project" title="Add project">Add another project</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is excellent, thanks! First, for solution to the problem, and then also the tips and reasons for them were very helpful to improve my knowledge and skills. I particularly like how you cleaned up my HTML so the drop-down menu and text field weren't duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

The IDs must be unique, instead whenever you add another row you duplicate the IDs.

Instead of IDs I changed them to class in order to combine **this** keyword with [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the values of interest.

Moreover, because you add new elements to the table you need to [delegate](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) the event.

If you change the select you need to calculate again, not only on typing into the input field.

```js
var addProject = $('.add_project');
var wrapper = $('.project_wrapper');
var projectHTML = '<tr>\
<td scope="row">\
        <select class="test_project" name="test_project[]" class="custom-select">\
        <option selected>Select</option>\
<option>10</option>\
<option>20</option>\
</select>\
</td>\
<td><input class="test_value" name="test_value[]" type="number" placeholder="Enter value"></td>\
        <td><div class="test_calc"></div></td>\
</tr>';

$(addProject).click(function () {
    $(wrapper).append(projectHTML);
});

$(document).on('input', '.test_value', function (e) {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.test_calc').text(Math.round($(this).val() * $(this).closest('tr').find('.test_project option:selected').val() || 0));
});

$(document).on('change', '.test_project', function(e) {
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.test_value').trigger('input');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>
    <tbody class="project_wrapper">
    <tr>
        <td scope="row">
            <select class="test_project" name="test_project[]">
                <option selected>Select</option>
                <option>10</option>
                <option>20</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input class="test_value" name="test_value[]" type="number" placeholder="Enter value"></td>
        <td>
            <div class="test_calc"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_project" title="Add project">Add another project</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer as well! And I appreciate you providing links to the relevant concepts.